# Why attribute of a dictionary works in template html through connection with codes in view.py ?

Tags: django, python-3.x, attributes

I am new to Django, and I am following a tutorial in which he writes something like

{%for post in posts %}

{{post.author}}

in the template html file. He describes that the template responds to the key 'posts'. To my understanding, post is a dictionary according to what he writes in view.py? How does it work?

```
posts = [
    {
        'author': 'JosephJ',
        'title': 'Blog Post1',
        'content': 'First post content',
        'date_posted': 'August 27, 2018'

    },
    {
       'author': 'RogerL',
        'title': 'Blog Post2',
        'content': 'Second post content',
        'date_posted': 'August 28, 2018'

    }
        ]

def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts': posts
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)
```

Comment: In your code snippet `context` is a dictionary, `posts` is a list that contains 2 dictionaries and `posts` is a key in the context dictionary. It's all Python syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `context ={ 'post_key': post_value }`
The left portion is the key and the right portion is the value.
The key is passed into template and its value is a queryset in Django.

for ex: `post_value = PostModel.objects.all()` It is the queryset that is assigned to the "post_value"